# Multiple Output Model while using Imagedatagenerator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-science, data-augmentation

Is it possible to use Imagedatagenerator with flow_from_directory with multiple outputs?

I wanna spilt the model like in the picture below.
My problem is that the Output on the left side is class_mode=categorical and the other ones are binary. I can already comile the model but I have no idea how to deal with the labels if I wanna use flow_from_directory.
Is there any way to use flow_from_directory with multiple outputs?

[model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eheXj.png)

Comment: what are your targets? where are they coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageDataGenerator as you normal would. You will have to use the Keras functional API. Let's look at this example that we would use transfer learning in but I will keep the same end structure as your network.

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(400,400,3))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten(x)
x1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
output1 = Dense(20,activation='softmax', name='toutput')(x1)

y = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
y = Dense(512, activation='relu')(y)
output2 = Dense(2,activation='softmax', name='r_output')(y)
output3 = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='ri_output')(y)
output4 = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name='li_output')(y)
```

Now the network has 4 outputs just like your picture. Now we can compile and give each output its own loss function. We can refer to each output by its 'name'.

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=.0001)
losses = {
    'toutput': 'categorical_crossentropy',
    'r_output': "mean_absolute_error",
    'ri_output': "mean_absolute_error",
    'li_output': "mean_squared_error",
    }
```

If you want specific metrics, you can do:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, metrics={'toutput':'accuracy', ...)
```

Comment: ImageDataGenerator outputs a label based on directory structure. How can it output 4 different outputs?

Comment: Based on exactly what you wan to output, you can use tf.dataset to match the other attributes. For example, you can iterate over each batch and match it to a tf.dataset entry, I recommend using tfrecord. You can then return that entry and the original data from the generator

Comment: Thanks. The advise to use tf.dataset sounds promising.